# EXPLANATION - Google activation link weird

Tags: email, gmail, verification

I have a question about a Google activation link.
When you create a new mail address, you receive a link like this (Fake One):

https://mail.google.com/mail/f-%5BANGjdJ_8Z7Enk13564864AE8hEWwrsY99osK-inpSk80nHe7HE7JAERuQF1TdJXVV_opJW-u74RImwgQa3oP91O2xiPax_Y-v3LduJD2zQ%5D-CiZzUTW_oOmBqJeFB_oq6u-RoTu

But what is that? How is it generated ?

> f-%5BANGjdJ_8Z7Enk13564864AE8hEWwrsY99osK-inpSk80nHe7HE7JAERuQF1TdJXVV_opJW-u74RImwgQa3oP91O2xiPax_Y-v3LduJD2zQ%5D-CiZzUTW_oOmBqJeFB_oq6u-RoTu
>   ?

For my website, I use GET information with a token in the link.

If someone know that :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to open links in a new tab, so you can go back easily, use this shortcut: `CTRL + left click`.

And now, for your question:

Google makes their links and codes hard to decipher, in order to prevent anyone from copying their ways of doing things.

Just like when you search something on Google, it says google.com/query-your-search-words-or-whatever but also with a whole longer code after.

For example, just the homepage gets a link like this one:

https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=pB4cVtLLBNKs8wfKyISQDQ

And, when you view the code of Google's home page: [are we serious?](http://view-source:https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=pB4cVtLLBNKs8wfKyISQDQ) (if link doesn't work, go to https://www.Google.com , then hit `CTRL + U` (Command + Option + u on Mac).

This can't be necessary, right?

All the best!